# ipfs with ethereum

Tags: blockchain, javascript, nodejs, ethereumjs, ipfs

Module not found: Can't resolve 'ipfs-api' in 'C:\Users.......\src'

I have used this code

```
//using the infura.io node, otherwise ipfs requires you to run a //daemon on your own computer/server.
const IPFS = require('ipfs-api');
const ipfs = new IPFS({ host: 'ipfs.infura.io', port: 5001, protocol: 'https' });
//run with local daemon
// const ipfsApi = require(‘ipfs-api’);
// const ipfs = new ipfsApi(‘localhost’, ‘5001’, {protocol:‘http’});
export default ipfs;
```

Comment: Did you run ``npm i ipfs-api`` ?

Comment: ipfs-api has been deprecated as indicated on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-api), instead of **ipfs-api** install **ipfs-http-client** [ipfs-http-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-http-client)